# params is undefined in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have the below function in `app/api/hello/[slug]/route.ts`

when I console log I get undefined . why ???

app/api/hello/[slug]/route.ts

```
export async function GET({ params }: any) {
    console.log(params);
}
```

log

```
- wait compiling /api/hello/[slug]/route (client and server)...
- event compiled successfully in 308 ms (65 modules)
undefined
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because first param is `Request`

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {}
```

And params is 2nd param (optional)

```
export async function GET(request: Request, { params }: any) {}
```

---

So the final code should be:

```
export async function GET(request: Request, { params }: any) {
    console.log(params);
```

You can make it specific by specifying the type of slug

```
export async function GET(request: Request, { params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  console.log(params);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are destructuring the Request object (which has no *params* key)

The parameters object is the second argument.

```js
export async function GET(request: Request, { params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  console.log(request.url, params);
}
```

You may have a look at the NextJS documentation about **Dynamic Route Segments**:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#dynamic-route-segments